# Stop update statement without damaging my database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran an update statement on my computer on a very big table 250 million records (the update is a big complex so it is taking too long)

Now the update is being running for 19 hours

[image]

I have been in similar situations before but when I click the stop button I the rollback process take way too long

and I am not sure at which is stage I am now, shall I keep it running as it MAY end soon or to stop and rollback which may take long time to finish.

I wonder if there is a way to know that?

Anyway, if not, is there anyway to make sure that the stop would not corrupt my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are executing your query in a transaction context then it should not harm your database if you kill the process.

Normally you should consider that the cancellation might take same time for which it ran.

If you killed the process and it's rollbacking then you can check the status with:

```
kill 52 with statusonly
```

You need to  know the spid you just killed.
If you have already killed the process and you don't know the spid then you can execute below query:

```
 SELECT spid
,kpid
,login_time
,last_batch
,status
,hostname
,nt_username
,loginame
,hostprocess
,cpu
,memusage
,physical_io
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE cmd = 'KILLED/ROLLBACK'
```

If you see no hope anymore than you can restart the service but it will send database in recovery mode which will make the database inaccessible for unknown amount of time. Once my production database was in recovery mode for 6 hours. So be very careful and only chose this option if you are hopeless.

You can query the table you are updating **with(nolock)** table hint to see how much data has been updated. But if it's taking too much time too then cancel it. (It would be much easier to track how many rows have been inserted than updated.)

```
(select * from tablename with(nolock) where...)
```

Comment: Everything in SQL server executes as a transaction, the default is to use implicit transactions. You'd have to be extremely unlucky to have data loss from killing a process. SQL Server is impressively robust!

Comment: Yup. Now a days loosing data is more difficult task.

Answer (score 2):

From another SSMS connection, you could `KILL [ServerProcessId]`

Using

```
Kill Id with statusonly
```

Will give you an estimate for the rollback to complete

Note that rollbacks will generally take much longer since they are always single threaded.

Additionally, you can find out a lot of useful information about what a process is doing by using [SP_WhoIsActive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/releases)

Additionally additionally, for future reference it's always advisable to run large data modification processes in batches if at all possible - you might want to check on the growth of your log file also.

You could choose a service restart, which would rollback from the transaction log, but that usually means the database is offline until it completes. Last resort only!

Answer (score 1):

The following query can tell you how far along the rollback has got:

```sql
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests;
```

Look at the `percent_complete` column. Please note that this is not always accurate, and may sit at 0 until the end of the query.

You can join it back to other views to get more info, eg:

```sql
select s.host_name, s.session_id, r.percent_complete
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
join sys.dm_exec_sessions s on s.session_id = r.session_id;
```